# Lock-free ping-pong in C11

Tags: c, multithreading, lock-free

I'm very new to concurrency in C and trying to do some basic staff to understand how it works.

I wanted to write a conforming implementation of lock-free ping-pong, i.e. one thread prints **ping**, after that another thread prints **pong** and make it lock-free. Here is my attempt of that:

```
#if ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE != 2
    #error atomic int should be always lock-free
#else
    static _Atomic int flag;
#endif

static void *ping(void *ignored){
    while(1){
        int val = atomic_load_explicit(&flag, memory_order_acquire);
        if(val){
            printf("ping\n");
            atomic_store_explicit(&flag, !val, memory_order_release);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
static void *pong(void *ignored){
    while(1){
        int val = atomic_load_explicit(&flag, memory_order_acquire);
        if(!val){
            printf("pong\n");
            atomic_store_explicit(&flag, !val, memory_order_release);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int args, const char *argv[]){
    pthread_t pthread_ping;
    pthread_create(&pthread_ping, NULL, &ping, NULL);

    pthread_t pthread_pong;
    pthread_create(&pthread_pong, NULL, &pong, NULL);
}
```

I tested it a few times and it worked, but there are things that seems weird:

1. **It either lock-free or does not compile**

Since the Standard defines lock-free property to be equal to 2 in order all operations on the atomic type are always lock-free. In particular I checked the compile code and it looks as

```
sub    $0x8,%rsp
nopl   0x0(%rax)
mov    0x20104e(%rip),%eax        # 0x20202c <flag>
test   %eax,%eax
je     0xfd8 <ping+8>
lea    0xd0(%rip),%rdi        # 0x10b9
callq  0xbc0 <puts@plt>
movl   $0x0,0x201034(%rip)        # 0x20202c <flag>
jmp    0xfd8 <ping+8>
```

This seems ok and we don't even need some sort of fence since [Intel CPU](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf)s does not allow stores to be reordered with earlier loads. Such assumptions works only in case we know the hardware memory model which is not portable

2. **Using stdatomics with pthreads**

I'm stuck with glibc 2.27 where `threads.h` is not yet implemented. The question is if it is strictly-conforming to do so? Anyway this is sort of strange if we have atomics, but do not have threads. What is the conforming usage of `stdatomic`s in multithreaded application then?

Comment: Is the question only, are atomics useful without threads? The answer to that is _maybe_, since you can have shared memory even between single-threaded processes.

Comment: @Useless Actually 2 questions. 1. Is it possible to make such a program guaranteely lock-free? 2. Is it conforming to `N1570 ISO/IEC 9899:201x` (or just okay if we take into consideration that we are using `pthread`s on `Linux`) to use `stdatomic`s with `pthread`s (or any other threading implementation)?

Comment: "Is it conforming ...."  Conforming to what? ISO/IEC 9899:2011?

Comment: @4386427 Yes. I'm considering `N1570 ISO/IEC 9899:2011` and in fact trying to understand how to make use of `stdatomic`s with absent of `threads.h`. Does the Standard gurantee the atomic's behavior to be well-defined with all threading implementations (like `pthread`s, erlier `LinuxThread`s, etc...)

Comment: @SomeName This unclear to me. You say you want to know if the code is confirming to the C11 standard but the code uses pthread which is not in the standard. Also I don't see how the assembly code and some Intel specific behavior is relevant if you want to know if some C is conforming to the standard.

Comment: @SomeName: There's a "memory hierarchy" (the relationship between caches, buses/links, memory controllers, RAM chips, ...). An operation is atomic if nothing else sharing (any part of) the memory hierarchy can interfere with the operation (including devices doing DMA/bus mastering, interrupt handlers, kernel code, various CPU features that cause reads/writes, other CPUs running threads in the same or different process, ...) .

Comment: @4386427 Probably the wording in the question is weird. As far as I understand what is specified in `5.1.2.3`: _Under a hosted implementation, a program can have more than one thread of execution (or thread) running concurrently. The execution of each thread proceeds as defined by the remainder of this standard._ it is not mentioned that the threads are exactly from `threads.h`, but as defined in the hosted environment. So the visibility guarantees provided by `stdatomic` should have been consistent with `pthreads` as well. Isn't such reasoning correct?

Comment: @4386427 Since I wanted exact lock-free behavior I looked at assembly fragment to make sure...

Comment: @Brendan So this seems `stdatomic`s can be used any time I need atomicity/memory ordering guarantees (even if `threads.h` are not implemented)...

Comment: @SomeName: If the compiler/library isn't broken and wrong; `stdatomic` should ensure anything atomic is "atomic from the perspective of any possible external observer" (regardless of whether threads are implemented or used, and which kind of threads). Note that for threads alone you'd only need "atomic from the perspective of another thread", which is significantly weaker than the "atomic from the perspective of any possible observer" that `stdatomic` is supposed to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 meanings to the term lock-free:

1. the computer science meaning: one thread getting stuck can't impede the others.  **This task is impossible to make lock-free, you *need* the threads to wait for each other**.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm)
2. using lockless atomics.  You're basically creating your own mechanism for making a thread block, waiting in a nasty spin-loop with no fallback to give up the CPU eventually.

The individual stdatomic load and store operations are each separately lock-free, but you're using them to create sort of a 2-thread lock.

---

Your attempt looks correct to me.  I don't see a way a thread can "miss" an update, because the other thread won't write another one until after this one finishes.  And I don't see a way for both threads to be inside their critical sections at once.

A more interesting test would be using unlocked stdio operations, like
**`fputs_unlocked("ping\n", stdio);`** to take advantage of (and depend on) the fact that you've already guaranteed mutual exclusion between threads.  See [unlocked_stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/unlocked_stdio.3.html).

And test with output redirected to a file, so stdio is full buffered instead of line-buffered.  (A system call like `write()` is fully serializing anyway, like `atomic_thread_fence(mo_seq_cst)`.)

---

> It either lock-free or does not compile

Ok, why is that weird?  You chose to do that.  It's not necessary; the algorithm would still work on C implementations without always-lock-free `atomic_int`.

`atomic_bool` *might* be a better choice, being lock-free on more platforms including 8-bit platforms where `int` takes 2 registers (because it has to be at least 16-bit).  Implementations are free to make `atomic_bool` a 4-byte type on platforms where that's more efficient, but IDK if any actually do.  (On some non-x86 platforms, byte loads / stores cost an extra cycle of latency to read/write in cache.  Negligible here because you're always dealing with the inter-core cache miss case.)

You'd think [`atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_flag) would be the right choice for this, but it only provides test-and-set, and clear, as RMW operations.  *Not* plain load or store.

> Such assumptions works only in case we know the hardware memory model which is not portable

Yes, but this no-barriers asm code gen only happens *while compiling for x86*.  Compilers can and should apply the as-if rule to create asm that runs on the compile target *as if* the C source was running on the C abstract machine.

---

> Using stdatomics with pthreads
>
> Does the ISO C Standard guarantee the atomic's behavior to be well-defined with all threading implementations (like pthreads, earlier LinuxThreads, etc...)

No, ISO C has nothing to say about language extensions like POSIX.

It does say in a footnote (not normative) that lockless atomics *should* be address-free so they work between different processes accessing the same shared memory.  (Or maybe this footnote is only in ISO C++, I didn't go and re-check).

That's the only case I can think of ISO C or C++ trying to prescribe behaviour for extensions.

But the *POSIX* standard hopefully says something about stdatomic!  That's where you should look; it extends ISO C, not the other way around, so pthreads is the standard that would have to specify that its threads work like C11 `thread.h` and that atomics work.

**In practice of course, stdatomic is 100% fine with any threading implementation where all threads share the same virtual address space.**  This includes non-lock-free things like `_Atomic my_large_struct foo;`.